# Laravel 9 set custom email SMTP configuration

Tags: php, laravel

My system is simple. if the user clicks the test button i need to send a text email to the same email id which i used.

[image]

i have tried to set config in my controller

```
config(['mail.username' => $username]);
```

but it gives error (Auth error)

I need a step by step approach to be done for this system.

Comment: Have you set the SMTP settings within the .env file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No the default value is null.

Comment: I want to set the mail SMTP details to be fetched from database and use to send emails with data...